# How to apply a function to a list only if element is a number

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have these lists:

```
ls1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
ls3 = {"Chales", 10, 10, 10};


ls5 = ls1 + ls3
```

`ls5` returns `{1 + "Chales", 12, 13, 14}`,

How do I make it return `{1, 12, 13, 14}` i.e. assume that when there is no valid number (e.g. a negative, no value or a string), apply a zero instead.

I have a huge dataset and sometimes some cells are corrupted so I want to handle automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can use `Replace` with the rule `Except[_?NumberQ] -> 0` and the explicit level specification `{1}`.

```
Replace[ls1, Except[_?NumberQ] -> 0, {1}] + Replace[ls3, Except[_?NumberQ] -> 0, {1}]
```

> {1, 12, 13, 14}

Or slightly shorter:

```
Plus @@ (Replace[#, Except[_?NumberQ] -> 0, {1}] & /@ {ls1, ls3})
```

Comment: It might be good to note add a note on the level specification. Generally one might want to use `{k}`. It is only for `k==1` that `{k}` and `k` are equivalent.  `Except` is very general and might otherwise eat unexpected parts of the expression.

Comment: Very good point.

Comment: It might be a good idea to replace with `Missing` instead of `0`, and replace the missing data when all is done.  E.g., `Replace[ls3, {Except[x_?NumberQ] -> Missing["Corrupt", x]}, {1}]`.

Comment: Thanks Henrik, it worked perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome, Enrique! (Great first name, btw... :) )